# What is the use of '||=' assignment operator in perl scripting?

Tags: perl, operators, perl-module, assignment-operator

I am using this line of code :

```
$sheet -> {MaxRow} ||= $sheet -> {MinRow};
```

in my script. 
I don't understand help me.

Answer (score 0):

`||=` means 'or equals', so if MaxRow is `0` or any other false value, MaxRow will get set to the value of MinRow.

`||=` is one of the Assignment Operators which is well described in
[`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Assignment-Operators)

A common use for `||=` would be to define a default value for optional subroutine variables.

```
my $data = { foo => 123, bar => 456, baz => 789 };
process($data);

sub process {
    my ($data, $is_special) = @_;
    $is_special ||= 0; # Typically not special
    do_something($data);
    do_special($data) if $is_special;
}
```

As Sobrique suggests, an 'or-cache' is another common use case to save yourself computing some expensive function.

```
my $fib_cache = [];
sub fib {
    my ($n) = @_;
    return 1 if ($n == 0);
    return 1 if ($n == 1);
    $fib_cache->[$n] ||= fib($n-1) + fib($n-2); # Only compute if not seen before.
    sleep(1); # To make this slow enough...
    return $fib_cache->[$n];
}

print "Fib 10 is " . fib(10) . "\n";   # Takes 10 seconds...
print "Fib 10 is " . fib(10) . "\n";   # Instant
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that is a typical operation - because it'd still work based on being `defined` or not. I'd probably suggest an "or-cache" type answer: `$cache{$key} ||= calculate_some_value_for($key);`